# Python error in while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am coding an impossible quiz game, and it doest work. I want the program to exit when the var `fails` is equal to 3.

Instead, when you enter a wrong answer three times, the program loops rather quitting.

```
    print("Welcome to impossible quiz")
    print("")
    print("You get 3 fails then you're out")
    print("")
    startcode = int(input("Enter 0 to continue: "))
    fails = 0
    if startcode != 0:
        exit(1)

    print("Welcome")
    print("")
    print("Level one")
    L1ans = input("1+1= ")
    while L1ans != "window":
        print("incorect")
        fails = fails + 1
        L1ans = input("1+1= ")
        if fails = 3:
            exit(1)
```

Comment: Try if fails == 3:

Comment: That should produce a syntax error, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a bit convoluted, and you have a syntax error. Try this:

```
fails = 0  # Set your failure flag
correct = False  # Set your correct flag
while not correct:  # if not correct loop
    answer = input("1+1= ")  # get the user's answer here
    correct = answer == "window"  # check for correctness
    if not correct:  # Handle incorrect case
        print("Incorrect.")
        fails += 1
        if fails > 3:  # quit if we've looped too much. > is better than == for this
            exit()
print("Correct!")
```

Note that this is easily encapsulated in a class that can handle any question:

```
def ask_question(question, answer, fails) {
    correct = False  # Set your correct flag
    while not correct:  # if not correct loop
        answer = input(question)  # get the user's answer here
        correct = answer == answer  # check for correctness
        if not correct:  # Handle incorrect case
            print("Incorrect.")
            fails += 1
            if fails > 3:  # quit if we've looped too much. > is better than == for this
                exit()
    print("Correct!")
    return fails
}

fails = 0
fails = ask_question("1+1= ", "window", fails)
fails = ask_question("Red and earth is", "Macintosh", fails)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if fails == 3:
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I can only see 1 problem with your code, so your were nearly there!
Your if statement needs to have 2 equal symbols.

```
    if fails == 3:
        exit(1)
```